# jQuery load() doesn't work on IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery

the code below doesn't work with IE8 and Chrome but only work with Firefox.

FYI, I'm using Dreamweaver CS5.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#buttonEphone').click(function() {
  $('#apDiv2').load('ePhone.html');
 });

 $('#buttonEPC').click(function() {
  $('#apDiv2').load('ePC.html');
 });
});
```

Comment: Are you working with a local file (as opposed to a url starting with http://)? If so, I suspect this is a security restriction of chrome and IE, not a jquery problem.

Comment: have you tried debugging it in Chrome?

Comment: +1 for local file problem. I get that every now and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comment, this sounds like you are using a local html file, and not a url starting with `http://`. If that is the case, than I suspect that your problem is with security restrictions of chrome and IE on local ajax, not with jQuery (I incidentally encountered this problem with Chrome a few weeks ago).